# How to get a warning on old exception specifications

Tags: c++, c++11, g++4.8, exception-specification

I know that among other things (like auto_ptr), exception specifications have been deprecated in C++11.

Is there any way to get a warning from g++ 4.8 with the following code ?

```
struct F{
    void foo() throw (int){}
};
int main()
{
}
```

I already tried with **-Wall -pedantic -Wextra -Wdeprecated-declarations**, but without any success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
class __attribute__((deprecated)) old_style_throw_specification;
class old_style_throw_specification {};

#define throw(...) throw(old_style_throw_specification, __VA_ARGS__)
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98f2f74bddf9079c)

or if you need to support empty throw specifications (thanks @John5342 for pointing this out), you can use

```
#define throw(...) throw(old_style_throw_specification, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

for the macros but you'll need to compile with the GNU-extensions: `-std=gnu++11` as the above is not strictly legal C++11.

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aed2a51b9ab404fb)

Comment: I get error: expected initializer before 'throw'. It seems to be ill-formed somehow.Moreover, I would like to avoid macro. The legacy code Im working on is already full of nasty macros.

Comment: @Davidbrcz Fixed, should work now. (OK, still a macro)

Comment: Not sure that this would work with empty exception lists (there would be an extra comma). I think gcc has an extension for that though which i think goes ‘ throw(old_style_throw_specification, ##__VA_ARGS__)‘ where gcc will remove the extra comma if __VA_ARGS__ is empty.

Comment: @John5342 Sorry for the lag, I'm currently sick. And thanks for pointing out the problem with the empty throw specification, I updated the answer.